# How to get the last ten days partition count for 150+ tables quicly

Tags: hive

I have 150+ tables in Hive . Need to find the last ten days partition count to be run every ten days. We have written a query .

`hive -S -e "select count(*) from tblname where partitionname = '2019-07-10'"`

is there any other way to optimize the query to fetch the results quickly. it is running for more than 8 to 10 hours to fetch 10 days results for 150+ tables.Need help.

Comment: hi, your condition it's correct written ("..partitionname = 'date'") or should be "..partiitonname <='date'" ?

Comment: can you run this command and tell us the result? `set hive.stats.autogather;`

Comment: hive.stats.autogather=true . I would like to get the results quickly as much as possible . Will it be possible to query the metadata information .